# Pandas drop nan using first valid index by group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nan

I'm working with the following DataFrame:

```
         Date    Id    Amount
   0    201301    1      nan
   1    201302    1      nan
   2    201303    1      100
   3    201304    1      120
   4    201305    1      nan
   5    201306    1      120
   6    201302    2      nan
   7    201303    2      150
   8    201304    2      180
```

I'm trying to get the first valid index of `Amount` by `Id`. Because of some reason this doesn't work:

```
df.groupby('Id').Amount.first_valid_index()
```

I'm also trying this:

```
df.groupby('Id').Amount.apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index())
```

But my dataset is 20M+ rows, so it's taking too long and that won't work for me.

Is there any faster way to find the first index by group?

My desired output would be:

```
first_idx = [2,7]
```

Or even better:

```
         Date    Id    Amount

   2    201303    1      100
   3    201304    1      120
   4    201305    1      nan
   5    201306    1      120
   7    201303    2      150
   8    201304    2      180
```

Edit: `df.groupby('Id').Amount.apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index())` indeed works, but I have the feeling there has to be a faster option, the problem doesn't seem to be that complex.

Comment: `df.groupby('Id')['Amount'].apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index)` ? Avoid `lambda`

Comment: @harvpan why doyou think avoiding `lambda` would make it any faster?

Comment: @QuangHoang doesn't it? I am *asking*

Comment: Appology, the way you put *Avoid lambda* sounds like a confirmation to me. The problem with OP's code, I believe, is actually `apply` which does not vectorized across the groups.

Comment: My first thought is that 'nan' is a string and not really np.nan.   Clues to why I think this.  In pandas, most of times pandas converts integer dataypes to float when np.nan is present in a column, I don't see any decimal number in Amount.  To correct this use df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].replace('nan', np.nan) and then try using first_valid_index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1:** To get just the first indexes:

```
df[df.Amount.notna()].groupby('Id').Date.idxmin()
# 1.42 ms ± 14.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

outputs:

```
Id
1    2
2    7
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

**Option 2:** to get the other rows, use `cumsum` on `notna()`

```
df[df['Amount'].notna().groupby(df['Id']).cumsum().gt(0)]
# 2.09 ms ± 220 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Option 3:** you can `ffill()` within group and choose those are not filled:

```
df[df.groupby('Id').Amount.ffill().notna()]
# 831 µs ± 14.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Output:

```
     Date  Id  Amount
2  201303   1   100.0
3  201304   1   120.0
4  201305   1     NaN
5  201306   1   120.0
7  201303   2   150.0
8  201304   2   180.0
```

**Conclusion**: Option 3 is the fastest!

---

**Update:** to filter both ends using Option 3:

```
amt_group = df.groupby('Id').Amount
df[amt_group.bfill().notna() & amt_group.ffill().notna()]
```

Comment: The problem is I also need to find the last valid index, so ffill doesn't work in this case . How could I use option 2 to also keep until the last valid index?

Comment: Still Option 3 is fastest, do it twice, once with `ffill()` and one with `bfill()`. Btw, you should probably update your question/data to reflect that.

Comment: It's true! I thought I would have use `first_valid_index()` and so I thought then `last_valid_index()` would suffice, but there were better options

Comment: Worked like a charm and it's the fastest way, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Create a mask with `.notnull` + `.cumsum` to get everything after the first non-null `Amount` within the group. Then make a slice.

```
m = df.Amount.notnull().groupby(df.Id).cumsum().ge(1)

df.loc[m]
     Date  Id  Amount
2  201303   1   100.0
3  201304   1   120.0
4  201305   1     NaN
5  201306   1   120.0
7  201303   2   150.0
8  201304   2   180.0
```

Comment: Using `cummax` will save the chain of `ge(1)` as in `df.Amount.notna().groupby(df.Id).cummax()`  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot to both! If I wanted to do the same for the _last_ valid index it should suffice with sorting in the reverse order and running the same line?

Answer (score 0):

In case shifting is also required (e.g. start from the index before the first valid index). Using ffill() and shift() as chained calls would shift the frame and not the groups.

```
ffilled = df['Amount'].groupby('Id').ffill()
df[ffilled.groupby('Id').shift(-1, fill_value=True).notna()]
```